# How to pass a variable as credential to Jenkins invoke ansible playbook build step

Tags: ansible, jenkins-pipeline

**Requirement:**
I pull SSH credential (password rotational) from external source in my pipeline script and put into a variable. Then, I am trying to build another job (parameterized job) in the same pipeline script by passing the credential variable, but I have no idea how to use this input parameter variable as SSH credential to the build step (Invoke ansible playbook) as it only looks from already existing jenkins credential IDs.

**My Code:**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Trigger Cyberark Job') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def job1= build propagate: false, job: 'fetch_credential'
                    cred = job1.getBuildVariables()
                    def job2= build propagate: false, job: 'trigger_job', parameters: [string(name: 'INPUT', value: cred)]
```

**Challenge:**
Unable to use this variable "cred" in trigger_job as SSH credential in build step "Invoke ansible playbook". How to do?

Comment: There is a plugin to fetch cyberark secrets into jenkins credentials. https://docs.cyberark.com/conjur-enterprise/latest/en/Content/Integrations/jenkins.htm

Comment: @Zeitounator - Thankyou for the information. Let me check the configuration with respective team and update the status here

Comment: @Zeitounator - Cyberark Conjur is not available here due to licensing factor. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Get the secrets from cyberark and set them as Jenkins credentials by yourself then...